# Is there a more popular way of checking if there are results found in a database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public bool CheckForFieldViewByFieldIDIPAndUser( int fieldID, string ip, string userID )
{
    return this.context.FieldViewers.Where( x => 
        x.Field.FieldID == fieldID &&
        x.Viewer.IPAddress == ip &&
        x.Viewer.User.Id == userID ).Count() == 0;
}
```

I have used `.Count() == 0`. Is there a built in function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try FirstOrDefault()  , if it exist it return the object otherwise it returns a null.

Also you can use Any().

For example :

```
    public bool CheckForFieldViewByFieldIDIPAndUser( int fieldID, string ip, string userID )
{
    return this.context.FieldViewers.FirstOrDefault( x => 
        x.Field.FieldID == fieldID &&
        x.Viewer.IPAddress == ip &&
        x.Viewer.User.Id == userID )!= null;
}
```